# Hyper-V Replication of VMs with Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager and Symantec Mail Security

Tags: hyper-v, replication, symantec-endpoint-protection

I'm hoping for some advice on replicating Hyper-V VMs which are running Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager (SEPM) and Symantec Mail Security for Microsoft Exchange (SMSMSE). The problem is the large amount of replication data which is generated by antivirus definitions updates.

Each VM which is protected by SEPM generates approximately 3GB of data changes when the client is updated with new virus signatures. This is manageable, and I can randomise the distribution of these updates. Although, I would like to keep this as small as possible.

But, the VM running SEPM seems to be generating about 30GB a day in changes. I think this is because it keeps several versions of signatures to help with updating clients. Also, it has several copies of the data (as zipped files, expanded files, in inetpub, etc.)

The VM with SMSMSE also generates about 30GB of changes per day. Since we are running SEPM 12.1, we can't share definitions between these two products. So, we have two huge data stores which are updating regularly.

This is on a completely different scale from the actual business data being replicated, which is probably less than 5GB.

I've gone through all the various Symantec advice about reducing file storage, and I think I've done about everything I can without reducing the effectiveness of the product. I'm only storing 3 versions and only for the target operating systems required, etc. But, I'll take any advice about how I might reduce the storage required by SEPM and SMSMSE.

Assuming I can't reduce the size of the SEPM and SMSMSE data, are there many options for reducing the replication burden. For example, switch off replication for the SEPM and just have an overnight backup, rather than a replica for DR purposes. Or store the SEPM and SMSMSE data on a separate drive with data deduplication (if possible).

I'm new to Hyper-V replication and I'm hoping there are a few tricks to help with this situation.

Comment: When  you say Hyper-V replication do you mean Hyper-V Replica or do you mean something else?

Comment: There is one hyper-v host (running on Windows 2012 R2) at our primary site. There is another hyper-v host (also Windows 2012 R2) at our contingency site. The VM's running on the host at the primary site have a replication mode of "Primary" and are set up to replicate to the host at our contingency site, where the VM's have a replication mode of "Replica". There is a 50Mb line between the sites which can deal with the replication changes. But, it bugs me that Symantec is taking all the bandwidth.